# Родительский класс обращается к методу, объявленному только в дочернем классе. JS. Ext

Tags: javascript, ооп, наследование, полиморфизм, extjs

Собственно вопрос к полиморфизму в Js (как мне кажется).
Есть дочерний класс NewUserFormRF, расширяющий NewUserForm.

```
 Ext.define('Application.components.NewUserFormRF',{
      extend: 'Application.components.NewUserForm',
```

В нем есть метод:

```
getIds: function () {
    return initIds(["foo","bar","bas"]);
  },
```

Ниже приведен родительский класс:

```
Application.components.NewUserForm = Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel, {
```

В родительском классе этот метод используется следующим образом:

```
initComponent: function () {
    this.addEvents('doRegister');
    var component = this;
    this.ids = initIds([
          "bla",
          "xyz",
        ]);
    Ext.apply(this.ids, component.getIds());

Application.components.NewUserForm.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
```

В этом классе нет метода getIds(), и нигде выше нет объявления данного метода.
Засим вопрос: как родительский класс обращается к методу объявленному ТОЛЬКО в дочернем классе.

Comment: никак, если в другом дочернем компоненте не будет getIds все упадет

Comment: как понять в другом дочернем компоненте? можно поподробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: сейчас у тебя есть `Ext.define('Application.components.NewUserFormRF',{
      extend: 'Application.components.NewUserForm',` - если ты сделаешь еще один точно такой же только без метода getIds - то все упадет при попытке его создать

Comment: да, у меня есть еще 3 таких же подкласса где используется этот метод, но в родительском его нет как я указал. А в чем логика такой работы? где можно почитать подробнее? в пхп если в родителе метод не указан то он не вызовется.

Comment: `var component = this;` вот тут `this` - это объект дочернего класса, а у дочернего класса этот метод есть.

Comment: у меня были подозрения на var component = this; Но как понять что this  в этом случае указывается на объект дочернего класса?

Comment: вообще нужен более полный код. Как минимум в `initComponent.call(this);` ты явно передаешь `this`

Comment: понял, спасибо. последний вопрос - какой раздел подробнее прочитать про это?

Comment: про что конкретно?

Comment: 'var' - это зло. делайте нормальную типизацию переменных и будет Вам счастье. И сразу отпадут ненужные вопросы.

Comment: @Grundy
 про initComponent.call(this)

Comment: @Андрей Туманов
если б это был мой проект то я бы за)

Comment: @АндрейТуманов, какая связь между `var` и типизацией переменных?

Comment: @Stieglits, в дубликате о том, как меняется `this`

Comment: дубликат почитал, но не особо понял. Видимо знаний не хватает. А этот как-то связано с прототипированием? Как я по итогу понял этот метод должен быть во всех дочках, но его может не быть нигде выше, так? Пардон, за пачку вопросов просто очень хочется разобраться в этой части ООП джс, мне кажется тут оно разница с ООП пхп

Comment: @Stieglits, _А этот как-то связано с прототипированием?_ - никак. Оно связано с `Application.components.NewUserForm.superclass.initComponent.call(this)` где ты явно задаешь `this` и теперь ты знаешь почему внутри метода он ссылается на то что ссылается

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!